# Shifting cells from left to up in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a `shift()` function that either shift by index or shift by columns (left or right). But I need to shift my cells to left and if it's already the first column, I need to shift just the cells (not entire index row) left and up as it will overwrite my existing values.

Eg.

```
------------------------------------------------------
|Name| Age    | Sex  | Salary| Status | 5    | 6     |
|John| 32     | Male | NaN   | NaN    | NaN  | NaN   |
|4000| Single | NaN  | NaN   | NaN    | NaN  | NaN   |
|May | 20     | NaN  | NaN   | Female | 2000 | Single|
------------------------------------------------------
```

This happens due to poor parsing but there's no way to fix that as it's out of my control. So in this example, second row should move up to respective columns and last row should shift affected cells to left instead of entire row shift left. Is this possible? How should I approach this?

Comment: Parsing is out of your control entirely? What part of the data acquisition do you control?

Comment: What is the source? - a csv file or excel?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile could only control data manipulation after what I get from the source. In a way, I'm re-parsing this in pandas

Comment: @davidbilla It's a csv file.

Comment: @AhSheng if it's a csv file, arent there just commas in those missing cells. I would envison a csv file like this
`Name,Age,Sex,Salary,Status,5,6
John,32,Male,,,,
,,,4000,Single,,
May,20,Female,2000,Single,`

Comment: Ah, @davidbilla beat me to it. If you are getting as a CSV, it would be nice to be able to see at least part of it.

Comment: @AhSheng are the fields always presented for all users?

Comment: @davidbilla Yes something in that manner. To be more precise, it's tab-separated and the source is giving me '\t' in unwanted places. I have more fields in front eg Address should be `'\t123 Baker street\t' but it's giving me '\t123 B\t aker \tStre\tet'` This pushes my original data and give me NaN when I split. This doesn't happen to header row. But I can't use `pd.read_csv(...,sep='\t')` because the header is 21 columns but some data could give 23 to 24 columns. So I'm actually trying breaking it line by line to "re-parse" it using pandas.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile i can't share the real one, an example is something like the one I gave David - for `May\t20\t123 B\t aker \tStre\tet\tFemale\t2000\tSingle`. So there's some fields that have delimiter in for some reason and it's pushing my data off actual columns. Another example is the line gets broken to next because of '\x0c'

Comment: @QuangHoang No, some fields can be actual null.

Comment: How do you know those fields are valid `null` or the `null` you want to shift?

Comment: Did you try replacing tabs with commas before you load the df?

Comment: @davidbilla Yes, it doesn't work because that doesn't change the fact that delimiters are appearing in the wrong places from source.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix for this sample data set:

pd.DataFrame(df.stack().values.reshape(-1,5),
             columns=df.columns[:5])

Output:

```
   Name Age     Sex Salary  Status
0  John  32    Male   4000  Single
1   May  20  Female   2000  Single
```